# JavaScript not working for hiding and showing of textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here is my javascript code:

```
function htmlshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "visible";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "none";
}

function jqshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "visible";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "none";
}

function csshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "visible";
}
```

This code is to hide and show the textboxes along with I have a HTML code in PHP page as below

```
<body>
<img src="/code.png" id="flip" onclick="showbox()" style="left: 0px; top: 20%; position: fixed; z-index: 99999;"></img>
<section id="codebox" >
<form action="/code.php" method="send" >
<table>
<tr>
<button onclick="javascript:htmlshw()">HTML</button>
<button onclick="javascript:csshw()">CSS</button>
<button onclick="javascript:jqshw()">JS</button>
</tr>
<tr class="c">
    <section id="ht" class='hm'style="display: block;"> 
    <textarea type="text" name="HTML" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['HTML']; ?></textarea>
    </section>
</tr>
<tr class="c">
    <section id="sc" class='cs' style="display: none;"> 
    <textarea type="text" name="CSS" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['CSS']; ?></textarea>
    </section>
</tr>
<tr class="c">
    <section id="jq" class='jq' style="display: none;"> 
    <textarea type="text" name="JS" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['JS']; ?></textarea>
    </section>
</tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Compile" style="position: fixed; right: 0px; top: 10px; z-index: 999999; "></input>
</table>
</form>
</section>

<section id="result">
<?php echo $_REQUEST['HTML']; ?>
</section>

</body>
```

According to design, I have placed the 3 buttons with assigning respective functions but it won't seems to be working. Is there any technical reason behind it?

Comment: Where are the buttons? I don't see you calling any function

Comment: It should be `.style.display = "block";` not `visble`

Comment: 'block' is not working thats why i am using visible as the statement will be false and it will show the answe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're meant to be using `display:block;`, not `visible`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvaunqev/)

```
<button onclick="javascript:htmlshw();">HTML</button>
<button onclick="javascript:jqshw();">JavaScript</button>
<button onclick="javascript:csshw();">CSS</button>

<section id="ht" class='hm'style="display: visible;">
    <textarea type="text" name="HTML" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['HTML']; ?></textarea>
</section>

</tr> 
<tr class="c">
    <section id="sc" class='cs' style="display: none;">

        <textarea type="text" name="CSS" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['CSS']; ?></textarea>
    </section>
</tr>
<tr class="c">
    <section id="jq" class='jq' style="display: none;">

        <textarea type="text" name="JS" ><?php echo $_REQUEST['JS']; ?></textarea>
    </section>
```

```
function htmlshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "none";
}

function jqshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "none";
}

function csshw(){
    document.getElementById('ht').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('jq').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('sc').style.display = "block";
}
```

Also, take your `button`'s out of your `form` so that they don't try and send the form. Also, `method='send'` isn't a proper `method`, it should be `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: Well with the code you provided, I got it to work. @abhishekbagul

Comment: @abhishekbagul maybe you are not calling your functions right, show us your full code

Comment: Use this: http://jsfiddle.net/wxc7tn8n/ Basically, take your `button`s out of your form to stop it from submitting the form.